# Como embeber app nodejs en aplicacion java

Tags: java, angularjs, nodejs, spring, app

Hay una aplicacion desarrollada en spring y angularjs , el problema esta que quieren hacer una app en nodejs y poder embeberla dentro de la aplicacion de java, me explico

Algo como que presiones un boton , y aparesca alado tu app de node , supongamos que se auna calculadora , una forma que se me ocurre seria con un iframe , tenieno la app node corriendo en un server y llamando al iframe con esa ruta cuando se presione el boton , sin embargo que otras formas hay? , y cual en si serian las mas recomendables,gracias.

PD:No hay posibilidad de cambiar la app de spring , y tampoco la app de node.

Comment: Hola Kevin, tu app es nodejs que es? un Single-Page Application? algo con React? con angular? o simplemente un MVC con HTML como salida?

Comment: mi app nodejs es una aplicacion usando angular universal.

Comment: Tu aplicacion no es nodejs, es una aplicacion Angular, nodejs es la plataforma donde la desarrollaste...

Comment: amigo trabajo con angular universal , uso nodejs para servir algunas rutas y en otras uso el outlet de angular2, no puedo dar mucho detalle pero si uso nodejs.

Comment: @KevinAB lo que quieres es embeber una simple app Angular (frontend) seguramente en otra aplicación Java usando X framework de Java, la integración que quieres hacer en es en el frontend por lo que la tecnologia del backend es irrelevante a menos que des algún detalle en especial como intercomunicacion entre las dos aplicaciones en el navegador... Nodejs es la plataforma donde has desarrollado la app Angular, por ende tu aplicación no es Nodejs es angular... estas confundido

Answer (score 4):

Simplemente referencia a la app nodejs dentro de un **`iframe`** y listo. Es la forma más rápida, sencilla y efectiva ya que, a efectos prácticos, se trata más bien de *embeber* una web dentro de otra, independientemente de que el backend esté en lenguajes distintos.

A parte de eso, te paso un par de proyectos interesantes por si te pueden servir de ayuda o darte nuevas ideas:

- [Trireme runs Node.js scripts inside the JVM](https://github.com/apigee/trireme)
- [Java Bindings for V8](https://github.com/eclipsesource/j2v8)

Answer (score 0):

ya que tu aplicación nodejs esta hecha utilizando Angular, puedes simplemente cargarla en un nodo del DOM y así no tener la necesidad de utilizar un iframe.

Si seguiste el [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html](Getting Started), habrás notado que al crear tu componente inicial defines su etiqueta html:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }
```

y luego lo montas en el HTML usando:

```
<my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
```

por lo que en tu aplicación Spring bastaría con incluir el bundle generado (JS, CSS, imagenes, etc) y aplicar la etiqueta que definiste como tu app.